# playframework route is only two times accessable

Tags: java, playframework, bitbucket, unirest

in my playframework project I've got a GET route:

```
GET             /dashboard/issues                    @controllers.Dashboard.getBitBucketTickets()
```

The Method looks like this:

```
@Singleton
public Result getBitBucketTickets() {

    String credentials = "J:Eb";
    String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(credentials.getBytes());

    String json = null;
    try {
        json = new Gson().toJson(Unirest.get("https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/t/frontend/issues?limit=5&status=new")
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
                .header("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8").asJson());
    } catch (UnirestException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }  
    return ok(json);
}
```

When I call the Route two Times I can't call it a thrid time. I have to restart the project.

What could be a problem in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never use Unirest, but there is a point in the [documentation](http://unirest.io/java.html) that you need to be aware of:

> Unirest starts a background event loop and your Java application won't
>   be able to exit until you manually shutdown all the threads by
>   invoking:
>
> `Unirest.shutdown();`

Usually I use `WSClient` with Play. It works perfectly: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWS

Comment: Okay Thanks then Ich will try it tomorrow

Comment: When I do this `WSRequest request = ws.url(url).setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded).get();`
I got an error at setHeader ... function setHeader() is not known ...

Comment: You need to add `javaWs` only once in the `build.sbt` file: `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
javaWs
)`

Comment: yes of course I did this `libraryDependencies ++= Seq( javaJdbc ,  cache , javaWs)`

Comment: Perhaps you use `play.api.libs.ws.WSClient` that is Scala class. Make sure that you use `play.libs.ws.WSClient`.